# "Nested" JSON to "unnested" JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I am trying to convert the JSON i get from an API to a different form of the same JSON in Javascript. 
My JSON has members, a lot of 'parents' (nested objects) and a lot of children (nested Arrays of objects). I'd love to make the parents members.

A sample of my JSON is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "street": [
      {
        "addressinfo": {
          "id": 110,
          "description": "Bezoekaddress"
        },
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hoogveldstraat"
      }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "searchName": "JacksIcecream",
    "chamberOfCommerce": ""
  },
  {
    "street": [],
    "id": 2,
    "searchName": "OAK",
    "chamberOfCommerce": ""
  }
]
```

and I am trying to convert it to the following:

```
 [
   {
    "street": [
      {
        "addressinfo_id": 110,
        "addressinfo_description": "Bezoekaddress",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hoogveldstraat"
      }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "searchName": "JacksIcecream",
    "chamberOfCommerce": ""
  },
  {
    "street": [],
    "id": 2,
    "searchName": "OAK",
    "chamberOfCommerce": ""
  }
]
```

I'm stuck on this for a while now, and i really cannot find any answer to this question, all the questions i can find are about flattening the arrays, while i only want to 'flatten the non-array-nested-objects'. How can I do something like this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's not clear what programming language you're using, or what you've tried.

Comment: @bn. OP is using Javascript. It says both in the title and tags.

Comment: Not to sound rude, but may I ask why you want to make the change? To me the first alternative looks cleaner.

Comment: [link](http://bl.ocks.org/nautat/4085017) I was using this, but somehow i could not manage to let the sample not display [Object object] for nested objects that are not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseObject(obj) {
    var i, path, x, type = ({}).toString.call(obj);
    if (type == "[object Array]") {
        for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            parseObject(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    else if (type == "[object Object]") {
        path = (arguments[1] && arguments[1].length) ? arguments[1] + "_" : "";
        for(i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                x = obj[i];
                if (path.length) {
                    delete obj[i];
                    obj[path + i] = x;
                }
                parseObject(x, path + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

tested as follows:

```
var x = [{
    "street": [{
        "addressinfo": {
            "id": 110,
            "description": "Bezoekaddress"
        },
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hoogveldstraat"
    }],
    "id": 1,
    "searchName": "JacksIcecream",
    "chamberOfCommerce": ""
}, {
    "street": [],
    "id": 2,
    "searchName": "OAK",
    "chamberOfCommerce": ""
}];
parseObject(x);
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

Output (run through http://jsbeautifier.org/ ):

```
[{
    "street": [{
        "addressinfo": {
            "addressinfo_id": 110,
            "addressinfo_description": "Bezoekaddress"
        },
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hoogveldstraat"
    }],
    "id": 1,
    "searchName": "JacksIcecream",
    "chamberOfCommerce": ""
}, {
    "street": [],
    "id": 2,
    "searchName": "OAK",
    "chamberOfCommerce": ""
}]
```

Comment: That differs from the output the OP asked for, which has no separate `addressinfo` hash.

Comment: you're right, but it took you 7 weeks to point it out :D (just kidding)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the elements in the top-level array, find the `street` array in each element, and loop over its members and manipulate their contents:

```
json . forEach(function(elt) {
  elt.street . forEach(function(street) {
    street.addressinfo_id = street.addressinfo.id;
    street.addressinfo_desc = street.addressinfo.desc;
    delete street.addressinfo;
  });
});
```

or were you looking for something more general and parameterizable?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

```js
// Convert Nested Json to Flat Json
// Check the final json in firebug console.
var fullData = {"data":[{"Vehicle":"BMW","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:24 AM","Location":"Hauz Khas, Enclave, New Delhi, Delhi, India","Speed":42,"Children":[{"Vehicle":"BMW","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:24 AM","Location":"Hauz Khas, Enclave, New Delhi, Delhi, India","Speed":42,"Children":[{"Vehicle":"BMW","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:24 AM","Location":"Hauz Khas, Enclave, New Delhi, Delhi, India","Speed":42,"Children":[]}]},{"Vehicle":"Honda CBR","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:00 AM","Location":"Military Road,  West Bengal 734013,  India","Speed":0,"Children":[]}]},{"Vehicle":"Honda CBR","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:00 AM","Location":"Military Road,  West Bengal 734013,  India","Speed":0,"Children":[]},{"Vehicle":"Supra","Date":"30, Jul 2013 07:53 AM","Location":"Sec-45, St. Angel's School, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":58,"Children":[]},{"Vehicle":"Land Cruiser","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:35 AM","Location":"DLF Phase I, Marble Market, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":83,"Children":[]},{"Vehicle":"Suzuki Swift","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:02 AM","Location":"Behind Central Bank RO, Ram Krishna Rd by-lane, Siliguri, West Bengal, India","Speed":0,"Children":[]},{"Vehicle":"Honda Civic","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:00 AM","Location":"Behind Central Bank RO, Ram Krishna Rd by-lane, Siliguri, West Bengal, India","Speed":0,"Children":[]},{"Vehicle":"Honda Accord","Date":"30, Jul 2013 11:05 AM","Location":"DLF Phase IV, Super Mart 1, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":71,"Children":[]}]}
var finalData = [];
loopJson(fullData.data);
function loopJson(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, e) {
        if (e.Children.length>0) {
            var ccd = e.Children;
            delete e.Children;
            finalData.push(e);
            loopJson(ccd);
        } else {
            delete e.Children;
            finalData.push(e);
        }
    });
}
console.log(finalData);
```

Here is the fiddle for it : http://jsfiddle.net/2nwm43yc/